# Spacecraft that can be used for microgravity missions and experiments

Tags: spacex

Do you know any of spacecraft that can be used for microgravity missions and experiments? Nowadays it`s rather popular and useful to use uncrewed guided space vehicles for particular microgravity missions. I found some of them that can even used in universities to collect data on the ambient conditions. If you can make an example one of them or maybe more, please share)